# generating pojo with base64binary type in xsd

Tags: jaxb, xsd, base64, adapter, xjc

in my project i am getting response in base64 format.
1) I have the response schema which defines element type as base64binary ex. `<xs:element name="title" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>`
2) i generate the pojo using xjc command. in the above ex. it will have getter setter method like

```
public byte[] getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

public void setTitle(byte[] value) {
        this.title = value;
    }
```

3) in my controller when i do getTitle() i get the base 64 encoded byte[] value.

Is there a way to directly getting decoded title value in String so this means if i do getTitle it should return decoded string value of title instead of returning encoded byte[].
How should i generate  the pojo which overrides default data type ie. byte[] to String? and how to write binding/adapter class.

Comment: The following will help with generating the `XmlAdapter`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html.  You should also check out the `DatatypeConverter` class:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html